# get-acl syntax problem

Tags: powershell

Could someone explain something to me?  If I run the command `(get-acl .\test.txt) | Select-Object owner`, I get

```
Owner
-----                                                                              
BUILTIN\Administrators
```

which is what I was expecting.  However, if I run the command `(get-acl .\test.txt) | Select-Object Access`, I get this:

```
Access
-----
{System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule,System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}
```

instead of the list of the users/groups who have permissions on that file and what those permissions are.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should probably give some background as to what I am trying to do.  There is a certain file on multiple machines that may have different permissions from one machine to the next.  I am trying to write a script that will list out the users with access to the file and remove ones that I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Access` property contains an array. You can expand it without walking a loop:

```
Get-Acl .\test.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access
```

Answer (score 1):

Those objects don't have a pretty string conversion when you're trying to print them, so they spit out their object type.

Try something along these lines:

```
(get-acl .\test.txt) | Select-Object Access | foreach-object { $_.identityreference }
```

Comment: Thanks!  That output was blank but that pointed me in the right direction.  The following gives me what I need:
(Get-Acl .\test.txt).Getaccessrules($true, $true, [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) | Select-Object IdentityReference